# Angular2 @HostBinding cannot bind on background-image style

Tags: typescript, angular, styles

When using [`@HostBinding`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostBinding-var.html) to bind a property to the background-image of my component, it doesn't work when I specify an image URL.

**First example with Angular2 RC-1 :**

```
import {Component, HostBinding} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    template: 'something'
})
export class DemoComponent {

    @HostBinding('style.background-image')
    backgroundImage = 'url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300)';
}
```

When inspecting the DOM, we can find `<demo>something</demo>` **-> NOT GOOD**

---

**Second example :**

```
import {Component, HostBinding} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    template: 'something'
})
export class DemoComponent {

    @HostBinding('style.background-image')
    backgroundImage = 'none';
}
```

This time, when inspecting the DOM, we can find `<demo style="background-image: none;">something</demo>` **-> GOOD**

---

I tried with `background` instead of `background-image`, it works with a color like `"blue"` but still doesn't work with an URL.

I also tried to dynamically change the value later with a `setTimeout` inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, it works when changing from `"none"` to `"blue"`, but not with an URL, the value stay `"none"`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the url in quotes like so: `backgroundImage = 'url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300")';`

Comment: Yes, I tried with quotes. I tried with a function insted of a variable. I tried with the `host` property inside the `@Component` decorator. Always the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a behavior because the style sanitizer of Angular2 was very restrictive... It seems to have been recently fixed.

See this issue:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8491
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8514 (fix)

Comment: It works with `DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustStyle()`. Thanks for the advise.